# How to make run only failed test cases in NUnit

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, nunit

Can anyone please tell me how to run only failed test cases using NUnit.

Answer (score 2):

NUnit does not provide this feature. There is no feature to re-run only the failed test cases.

Would can do is start only a couple of tests from the [command-line](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line) by their name:

> --test=NAMES  Comma-separated list of NAMES of tests to run or explore. This option may be repeated. Note that this option is retained for
>   backward compatibility. The --where option can now be used instead.
>
> --testlist=FILE   The name (or path) of a FILE containing a list of tests to run or explore, one per line.
>
> https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line

Now to create the list of tests to re-run you should be able to extract the failed tests from the [Test Result XML](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Result-XML-Format) file, but again there is no example code, you will need to create it yourself. Should not be to complicated for an average programmer, ask local developers for help.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to write an engine extension (IResultWriter) that would save a list of failed tests one per line in the same format that NUnit uses to run tests from the "--testlist" option.